# Most pragmatic way to model a type hierarchy in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, inheritance, polymorphism, subtyping

I have an abstract base type and a bunch of subtypes of it. Some of the subtypes are abstract on their own and have further subtypes.

I'd like to be able to define polymorphic function, some of which may be abstracts, while others have a default implementation that could be overloaded by some nodes.

What's the best way to model this in TypeScript?

In JavaScript I would use `class`es. This is a silly, simple example which shows what I would write. Please don't worry about the semantics, just about the sort of data that I'm trying to model.

```js
class Polygon {
    constructor( name ) { this.name = name; }
    // abstract methods
    area() { assert.fail(`${this.constructor.name} must implement area()`); }
    // methods with fallback implementation
    toString() {
        const props = Object.entries(this)
            .filter( ([k, v])=>k !== 'name' )
            .map( ([k, v])=>`${k}:${v}` )
            .join(", ");
        return `${this.name}{props}`;
    }
}
class Triangle extends Shape {
    constructor( base, height ) {
        super('TRIANGLE');
        this.base = base;
        this.height = height;
    }
    area() { return this.base*this.height/2; }
}
class Quadrilateral extends Shape {
    constructor( name, base, height ) {
        super(name);
        this.base = base;
        this.height = height;
    }
    area() { return this.base*this.height; }
}
class Square extends Quadrilateral {
    constructor( side ) {
        super( 'SQUARE', side, side );
    }
    area() { return this.base*this.height; }
    toString() { return `${this.name}{side:${this.base}}`; }
}
```

However converting this thing in TypeScript the naive way doesn't work too well:

1. The field `name` cannot be used as a discriminant for `Polygon`. If I want to use a proper discriminant I have to introduce: `type PolygonType = Triangle | Square;` and use `PolygonType` instead of `Polygon` as the type for unknown subtypes of it.
2. Using `class`es limits what I can express. For instance I couldn't use type level metaprogramming to help me define the exact shape of my types.

A more TypeScript-friendly implementation would be modeling my types using `type`s. But that would mean giving up polymorphism via prototype inheritance, as well as all the other perks of JavaScript `class`es.

I wonder whether there are other solutions to a similar problem, which I expect to be extremely common, and whether any is generally preferred.

Comment: Not answering your question: `base` and `height` are not enough to define a general quadrilateral

Comment: They're not enough to define a general triangle either. That's why I pointed out "Please don't worry about the semantics, just about the sort of data that I'm trying to model": I wanted to keep things simple, yet not completely abstract (it's hard to reason about similar problems when stuff is named `A`, `B`, `C`).

Comment: I wonder why you want to use discriminant field for classes. I use discriminants to carry type information for objects that are not instances of classes, if I need to have a runtime narrowing. For classes you have `instanceof`, so another type indicator is not necessary.

Comment: I like using the type discriminant for two reasons. 1. to encode/decode the object (if I dump it in JSON and then load it back, I can't use `instanceof`, but can use the name property to recreate the type). 2. to have maps from the object's type to a value... like `({ TRIANGLE(x:Triangle){...}, SQUARE(x:Square){...} })[polygon.name](polygon)`. Compared to inheritance-based polymorphism, this is the clean way to add new behavior later on (after the types have been defined); of course it can only be used if all the possible subtypes are known.

Comment: • "The field name cannot be used as a discriminant for Polygon." Right, it isn't one; nothing prevents another subtype of Polygon reusing a `name`. "If I want to use a proper discriminant I have to introduce:" Yes, that's how you'd do it. What's the drawback to that? How should the compiler know what you're doing otherwise? • "Using classes limits what I can express. For instance I couldn't use type level metaprogramming" please [edit] the question to demonstrate this limitation, I don't know why you can't use classes and also... generics? Is that what you're talking about?

Answer (score 0):

It seems using [interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) instead of types would be beneficial in this case.

First of all, interfaces specify types, so the goal will be achieved.

On the other hand, interface literally and historically is an abstract class without single implemented methods.

So, if it is a class, it can be extended for polymorphic purposes in the same way as class does:

```
interface Shape {
  area(): number
}
interface Polygon extends Shape {
  toString(): string
}


class Triangle implements Shape {}
class Square implements Polygon {}
```

You also can use base interface for dependency inversion.

```
class ShapeDrawer {
  draw(shape: Shape) {} // any Shape including Polygon or Square could be passed here.
}
```

Comment: How would you handle methods that need a default/fallback implementation, like the `toString` method in my example (defined in `Polygon`, then overloaded only in `Square`), or the base class `constructor`?

Comment: Another question: in your `ShapeDrawer`'s `draw` function, how would you use `shape.name` as a discriminant to narrow the shape down to its actual type?

Comment: @BlueNebula If we have common method implementation, then we can turn interface into abstract class. It still work exactly in the same way, but will have implementation.

The good practice when ShapeDrawer does not know about what Shape it uses, so you can pass any Shape with Shape interface.

If you need to depend on Polygon, then you should create PolygonDrawer(again, it can implement Drawer interface) and use it for Polygons exclusively.

Reading 'name' or 'type' to specify behavior of object is not a very good practice https://refactoring.guru/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#abstract-classes